# How is the limit of this equal to $\frac{\pi}{180}$

Tags: calculus, limits

**The problem is**: Find $\lim_\limits{{x\to0}} \frac{\sin x^\circ}{x}$.

**My attempt**:Here $x$ is clearly in degrees.

$$\therefore\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x^\circ}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi x}{180}}{\frac{\pi x}{180}}=1$$.

The answer given in my book is $\frac{\pi}{180}$. Where have i gone wrong or is the answer given in my book wrong. Also if $x$ is in degrees, isn't $\lim_\limits{{x\to0}} \frac{\sin x^\circ}{x}=1$ directly?

Comment: $x$ is not in degrees, $x^\circ$ is in degrees

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Then what is $x$ in?Radians?

Comment: Look at it this way: $x^\circ=x\cdot 1^\circ=x\cdot{\pi\over180}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply consider
$$
x^\circ=\frac{\pi}{180}x
$$
Then you can set $t=\pi x/180$ and the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{\frac{180}{\pi}t}=\frac{\pi}{180}
$$
Your mistake is in “$x$ is clearly in degrees”, which it's not: it's just a number.

Comment: Does the formula work when the argument of sine function and the denominator both are in degrees?

Comment: @MrAP Of course, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x^\circ}{x^\circ}=1$, because $^\circ$ actually is just a shorthand for “multiply by $\pi/180$”. It's much better if you forget about degrees and radians: the sine is just a function defined on the real numbers.

Comment: @egreg wait a minute egreg, is it not $x^o = {180\over \pi}x$ instead ? That's the first time I see this notation so I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @Furrane You want that $\sin30^\circ=1/2$, don't you? Since $30\cdot\frac{\pi}{180}=\pi/6$, this is correct.

Comment: Well $x^o \cdot {\pi\over 180} = x_{rad}$ is the same as what I wrote ain't it ?

Comment: @Furrane As said in another comment, I'd avoid referring to radians altogether.

Comment: @egreg The core of my issue here is that if you look at my answer, I end up with $180\over \pi$ instead of $\pi \over 180$

Comment: @Furrane You're using the wrong conversion.

Comment: Let say $x=\pi$, shouldn't we have $x^o = 180$ ?

Comment: @Furrane No, as the problem is stated, we should have that, for $x=180$, $\sin 180^\circ=0$.

Comment: Haaaaaaaaaa so it's like a $\sin^o$ function, ok I get it now, thanks for your patience, once again this is the first time I see this notation so I was confused, thanks egreg =)

Answer (score 0):

For x in radians, we know that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x_{rad} \thicksim x_{rad}$$

Note that I use $x_{rad}$ for what you call $x$ just to be clear here.

And we have the conversion $$x_{deg} = {180\over \pi}\cdot x_{rad}$$

So we have :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x_{deg} = \lim_{x\to 0}\sin \left({180\over \pi}\cdot x_{rad}\right) \thicksim {180\over \pi}\cdot x_{rad} $$

Hence :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\sin x_{deg}\over x_{rad}} \thicksim {{180\over \pi}\cdot x_{rad} \over x_{rad}} = {180\over \pi}$$

And that's not good since you wanted ${\pi \over 180}$